# Symbolic link for html file with an embeded flash swf located in different directory in redhat or centos Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, redhat, symlink

I have created a  html `index.html` which has an embeded code linking to `index.swf` in an folder both these file are in the path say `/home/user-name/`

When i created a symbolic link to `index.html` in the path  `/home/user-name/Desktop` .  when i click on the symbolic link index.html file it opens in the browser but the flash file `index.swf` is not loaded . This issue is in only RPM flavour of Linux .

Any help appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving (or putting links to) index.html around, then you have to also move (or link to) index.swf to the same places. This is unless index.html refers to the **full path** of index.swf (like `"/home/user-name/index.swf"`).